# Retain Statement and Underscore

Tags: sas

Consider the following data set **test**:

```
  x y
  1 A
  2 A
  . A
  4 A
  . B
  . B
  7 B
  8 B
```

Basically I want missing values in the group to be replaced by the previous value. But if the previous value is from another group then don't use that value to replace the current value.

Consider this code:

```
proc sort data=testout=Sorted;
   by y;
   run;


    data Out2(drop=_x);
    set Sorted;
    by y;

    retain _x;
    if first.y then do;

    _x=x;
    end; else do;

    if missing(x) then do;
    x = _x;
    end; else do;
    _x = x;
    end;

    end;

    run;
```

What does the underscore behind the x mean (_x)?

Answer (score 2):

Using an underscore as a prefix is a fairly common naming convention for temporary variables. As far as SAS is concerned, _x is just another variable - the _ doesn't have any special effect. However, if all your temporary variables (and only those ones) start with an underscore, it's a bit less work to tidy up at the end of your data step, because you can use a : wildcard to drop them all in one go. e.g.

```
data example;
  set sashelp.class;
  _age = age;
  _sex = sex;
  drop _: ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

`_x` is simply a new variable.  It could as easily be `z` or `last_x`.  However, it may be more clear to someone reading the code that it is related to x; while I'm not aware of any convention similar to "_ means previous value of ", it's not an unreasonable one.